# How can I become as advanced as David Carlisle or egreg?

Tags: luatex, latex3, learning

I have been using LaTeX for almost two years now and I have understood that the books I read gave me very little experince. The packages and tactics explained there are obsolete, for example,

- nothing about `xparse` and `expl3` packages, that allow to simply do cool things.
- Not a word about `Xe` or `LuaTeX` and `unicode-math` to use a variety of fonts.
- Nothing about the power of implemented `Lua` language.
- Usually, `Pstricks` or `xy-pic` graphics are discussed, while as I am awared, `TikZ` and `Asymptote` are much more powerful.

In fact, all my skills came from this very site, where I can ask a question and some almighty developers answer and get me aquainted with the powerful packages I have never heard before. For example, I discovered `aligned` (instead of `align`), `multlined` (instead of `multline`), etc. after asking a question here.

Also, my skills came from skills to read documentations, for example, `datatool` or `enumitem`.

My questions are:

- What literature should I read to begin becoming an advanced user?
- How to hear tools and packages you have never heard about before?
- What is the best way to discover newly released powers of doing something, rather than to continue using obsolete ones? (*speaking shortly: how to be stylish and up-to-date?)*. For example, `xparse` "o" option allows you to evade the hell of `\def\YourCommand{\@ifnextchar[{\@with}{\@without}}`

P. S. I hope the title of the question is not violating the rule not to go personal.

Comment: To answer the title of your question really short: It appears nobody can get as experienced as they are :)

Comment: I would suggest to start using it and create a package. The gurus on this site have created many packages and, also, have been using the TeX systems for decades. It's difficult to compare 20+ years with 2 years…

Comment: @Skillmon but some time ago they weren't as advanced as me *now*, so this gives me hope.

Comment: Read the daily questions and answers and see if you learn something new. Even if you don't have a question right now that gets you something interesting in an answer, another person might have a question and the answer might blow your mind.

Comment: I wouldn't say TiKZ or asymptote are much more powerful than pstricks. They do not have exactly the same facilities, and, in my opinion, pstricks is easier to learn.

Comment: Have you ever wondered How to explain LaTeX to your grand mother? or Drawing a TeX donkey? or Drawing a christmas tree or a pumpkin?

Comment: There are two different parts in that knowledge: know how TeX works (I learned through this site, and I don't know TeX to that level, but you can conform with much less knowledge); and also real world up to date knowledge about what is new in the TeX world, what works best, what new packages, etc. Both of them you can get from this site. With time you will get to understand TeX, and the up to date information you will gather just by reading answers or comments here. But may be you are a better “book learner”, I'm bad, and I learnt much more from randomly reading answers here than reading docs.

Comment: @Johannes_B yes, I have seen these discussions.

Comment: there seems to be a typo in your title,  surely you didn't mean the user egreg?

Comment: @Johannes_B You forgot `tikzducks` package!

Comment: There's no hope to reach them, give up!

Comment: Actually, expertise in TeX is acheived by sacrificing chickens. If you don't believe me, dig down through your TeX system, and find the folder named "chickenize." But don't you dare open it!

Comment: I want to echo what @Manuel said: there are multiple kinds of “skills” involved here: knowledge of TeX/LaTeX workings/internals, knowledge of the (La)TeX ecosystem/community, and skill in use thereof. (For example, consider that being an expert Java/Python programmer may mean/include any of: knowing the language very well, knowing the set of existing libraries (all the code that others have written), or simply being very skilled/experienced in accomplishing tasks using them.) Of course, people like egreg and David are great on all those counts.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

But still an awful christmas song regardless...

Comment: Actually, one *does* get more rep than the creator of `xii.tex`. :)  But only one.

Comment: @AlanMunn Only one dares to dissect the internet memes

Comment: [xii](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xii) is a single tex file which is super cryptic (@percusse, may I add the code of xii.tex here?)